# Create PowerPoint 2007 presentation from a template

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, openxml, presentationml

I need to create a PowerPoint 2007 presentation from a template with [Open XML Format SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0). The template has to be provided by the customer and is used for a individual layout style (font, background color or image,...). It needs to contain two predefined slides:

- Text slide
- Image slide

The application should now create a copy of the template file, create multiple copies of the text- and image slides and replace the content-placeholders with some content.

I already found some [code snippets from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8d46c01f-e3f6-4069-869d-90b8b096b556) to edit the title of a slide, delete them or replace a image on a slide. But i didn't find out how i can create a copy of a existing slide. Maybe somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking around for a similar answer and have found some resources to share:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850834(office.14).aspx

or more samples

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850828(office.14).aspx

or this website

http://www.openxmldeveloper.com

There is also this [free book documenting the OpenXML standard](http://openxmldeveloper.org/attachment/1970.ashx) which was somewhat helpful.

Comment: In your book link you're linking to local file. =P

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what I thing you're looking for, but if not, let me know: http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/7429.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For C#

```
File.Copy(SourceFile,ExportedFile);
```

You basically keep the original file.

Now you open ExportedFile

```
PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new PowerPoint.Application();
PowerPoint.Presentation presentation;
presentation = ppApp.Presentations.Open(ExportedFile, MsoTriState.msoFalse,   MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

Now iterate all slides/shapes

```
foreach (PowerPoint.Slide slide in presentation.Slides)
{
                    slide.Select();
                    foreach (PowerPoint.Shape shape in slide.Shapes)
                    {
                        if (shape.Type.ToString().Equals("<any type of shape>"))
                        {
                            if (shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Equals("<contains a name"))
                            {
                                shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = <new value>;
                                shape.Delete(); // or delete
                                shape.AddPicture(<your new picture>, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, left, top, width, height);

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

}

Hope this might clarify your request.